# Получить список файлов в директории и поддиректориях

Tags: windows, php

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо получить список файлов с расширением `.html` в директории и поддиректориях. Причем, чтобы было так, чтобы файл `index.html` в директории `privet` выдавался [так](http://site.ru/privet/index.html).

Поддиректорий очень много, а в этих поддиректориях есть еще поддиректории, из которых тоже нужно извлечь файлы, так что вручную собирать имена файлов (а их там 8 171) - не вариант.

Наработки.

```
<?php
$filename = "/";
foreach (glob("*.html") as $filename) {
    echo "http://site.ru/{$filename}<br/>";
}
?>
```

Спасибо.

P.S. OC - Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут вам в помощь только рекурсия. Завалялся у меня тут мой давний скриптец, как раз реализующий то, что вам надо:

```
function scan($path,&$res, $type="*", $type_sort="small", $lines=0)
{   
    $mass=scandir($path);  // данная функция основывается на стандартной функции PHP- 
                              scandir
    for($i=0;$i<=count($mass)-1;$i++)
    {
        if($mass[$i]!=".." && $mass[$i]!=".")  
        {   if(strtolower($type_sort)=="small")
        {
            if($type=="*" || strstr(strtolower($mass[$i]),$type))
            array_push($res,array($lines,$mass[$i]));
        } else
            if($type=="*" || strstr(strtolower($mass[$i]),$type)) 
            array_push($res,array($lines,$path.$mass[$i]));
        }
        if(!strstr($mass[$i],".")) 
        if(is_dir($path.'/'.$mass[$i])) scan($path.'/'.$mass[$i],$res,$type,$type_sort,$lines+1);
        }

    }
```

Данная функция сканирует папку с подпапками **$path** с последующей записью полных имен файлов в массив, переданный по ссылке **$res**. **$type** - тип файлов, которые надо искать. В вашем случае - это .htm/.html

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь навлечь гнев мэтров, но можете рассматривать, как запасной вариант:

```
// Функция, считывающая файлы из текущей директории
function get_files($path, $order = 0, $mask = '*') {
    $fdir = array();
    if (false !== ($files = scandir($path, $order))) {
        foreach ($files as $file_name) {
            if ($file_name != '.' && $file_name != '..' && fnmatch($mask, $file_name)) {
                $fdir[] = SITE_ADDR.$path.'/'.$file_name;
            }
        }
    }
    return ($fdir);
}

// Вам надо только изменить значения для двух нижних строк
define('SITE_ADDR','http://site.ru/'); // адрес сайта
$path = 'some_dir'; // директория, с которой стартовать сканирование

$d = dir($path);
if ($d) {
    $dirs = array($path);
    // Считываем все директории
    while (false !== ($name = $d->read())) {
        if ($name === '.' || $name === '..') continue;
        $fullPath = $path.'/'.$name;
        if (is_dir($fullPath)) {
            $dirs[] = $fullPath;
        }
    }
    $d->close();

    // Перебираем все найденные директории и отправляем
    // в функцию, для считывания в них файлов
    foreach($dirs as $cd){
        // Вызов функции get_files():
        // второй параметр - сортировка 1 или 0, 
        // третий параметр - расширение файлов
        $files .= implode('<br />',array_filter(get_files($cd, 0, '*.html'))).'<br />';
    }
    // Выводим файлы с полными путями
    echo $files;
}
```

Comment: Эта функция очень хорошо написана, единственное что нужно так это ссылки на файлы .html 
Подскажите как сделать ссылки списком тегами: 

<ol> 
   <li> ссылка на файл .html или .htm </li>
</ol>


