# Ошибка 500 при попытке взять все файлы с директории и ее поддиректорий

Tags: php

Есть главная директория например

```
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/contents/';
```

В ней находятся файлы и поддиректории, которые тоже содержат файлы и тоже могут содержать поддиректории. Пытаюсь получить рекурсивно общий массив со всех файлов:

```
function allFiles($dir) {
    $files = [];
    foreach(glob($dir.'*') as $fileOrDir) {
        if(is_dir($fileOrDir)) {
            $files = array_merge($files, allFiles($fileOrDir));
        } else {
            $files[] = $fileOrDir; 
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

Но получаю ошибку **500 Internal Server Error**.

Видел ответы на вопрос по ссылке [Получить список файлов в директории и поддиректориях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/124432) но хотелось бы понять в чем проблема с моим более упрощенным вариантом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, выяснил в чем проблема. В строке с `array_merge()` нету слеша внутри аргумента функции т.е. вместо `allFiles($fileOrDir)` нужно `allFiles($fileOrDir.'/')`

Вот и вся проблема